ARDL Long-Run relationship on Eviews
I am using Eviews13 to make a regression, Y1 on X1, X2 and X3.
The long run equation looks like EC = Y1(-1) -[aX1 + bX2(-1) + cX3(-1)]
I am wondering how to extract the long run relationship (equation) directly from Eviews and be able to do some forecasts (directly) on it. I tried to re-estimate it using OLS but it doesn't give the same result.
P.S : please with no coding if possible
